# excel VBA remove columns based of header row in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, so I'm trying to remove columns that contain a specific value in my header rows on multiple sheets. If I remove the Activate Worksheet procedure and place the code on the desired sheet it works fine but this won't be an option. I have ~100 of files which were created with a xls template that I need to remove certain columns.

Below is what I'm trying to do with activating the sheet that contains the header value and the column to be removed.

The value I'm looking for in the examples below are RUA Hit Count, RUA Usage, RUA Start Date, RUA End Date and RUA Total Days. There will be roughly 50 columns removed from each workbook when all said in done.

```
Sub remove_columns()

Dim i As Integer

Worksheets("Sheet7").Activate
For i = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(1, i), "RUA Hit Count") Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate
For i = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(1, i), "RUA Usage") Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
For i = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(1, i), "RUA Start Date") Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
For i = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(1, i), "RUA End Date") Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
For i = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(1, i), "RUA Total Days") Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: After opening and modifying each XLS workbook, do you want to save the modified version as XLSX (or even XLSB)? You sample shows only one keyword applied to each; do you want *every* keyword applied to teh removal of columns for each worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

```
'Process all workbooks in a given folder
' - remove specified columns
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Collection, f, wb As Workbook

    Set c = GetExcels("C:\_Stuff\test") 'edit folder to suit
    For Each f In c
        Debug.Print f
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
        ProcessWorkbook wb
        wb.Close True 'save changes
    Next f
End Sub

'remove all unwanted columns from a workbook
Sub ProcessWorkbook(wb As Workbook)
    RemoveColumn wb.Worksheets("Sheet7"), "RUA Hit Count"
    RemoveColumn wb.Worksheets("Sheet5"), "RUA Usage"
    RemoveColumn wb.Worksheets("Sheet1"), "RUA Start Date"
    RemoveColumn wb.Worksheets("Sheet2"), "RUA End Date"
    RemoveColumn wb.Worksheets("Sheet3"), "RUA Total Days"
End Sub

'remove a column from a sheet if it exists
Sub RemoveColumn(sht As Worksheet, colName As String)
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = sht.Rows(1).Find(what:=colName, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then f.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

'get a collection of all Excel filenames (inc. path) in a folder
Function GetExcels(sDir As String) As Collection
    Dim c As New Collection, f
    If Right(sDir, 1) <> "\" Then sDir = sDir & "\"
    f = Dir(sDir & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        c.Add sDir & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    Set GetExcels = c
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure works for the ActiveWorkbook

It could be edited to work on an array of workbooks

It populates a dictionary with the search criteria for the column headers

It then checks each column header and deletes the column if it finds a match

```
'Tools->References
'Reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Dim intCount1 As Integer
Dim intCounter1 As Integer
Dim intColumnLast As Integer
Dim strHeader As String
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
Dim dictColumnHeader As Dictionary

'Populate dictionary
Set dictColumnHeader = New Dictionary
With dictColumnHeader
    .Add Key:="RUA Hit Count", Item:=1
    .Add Key:="RUA Usage", Item:=2
    .Add Key:="RUA Start Date", Item:=3
    .Add Key:="RUA End Date", Item:=4
    .Add Key:="RUA Total Days", Item:=5
End With

For Each wsTemp In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    wsTemp.Activate
    intColumnLast = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    intCount1 = 0
    'Check each column header to see if it matches bogus column headers loaded into dictionary
    For intCounter1 = intColumnLast To 1 Step -1
        'Assuming the header row is on row 1
        strHeader = Cells(1, intCounter1).Value
        If dictColumnHeader.Exists(strHeader) = True Then
            Cells(1, intCounter1).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next intCounter1
Next wsTemp
```